# IF, OR, MATCH FUNCTION IN EXCEL

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, match

do you guys know the error from this formula?

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(MATCH(D3,'Sheet1'!$O$7:$O$67,1),MATCH(D3,'Sheet2'!$O$7:$O$67,1),MATCH(D3,'Sheet3'!$O$7:$O$67,1)),"YES"),"NO")
```

I checked the formula but the result is always "NO", when I checked it manually the result should be "YES", is there anything that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

MATCH will return a number or an error.  If any of the expressions in the OR returns an error the entire OR returns an error, so you will always get the error return.

Instead wrap each MATCH in ISNUMBER:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D3,'Sheet1'!$O$7:$O$67,1)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(D3,'Sheet2'!$O$7:$O$67,1)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(D3,'Sheet3'!$O$7:$O$67,1))),"YES","NO")
```